# Problems with ASCII encoded string - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, curl, encoding

I'm parsing a page using php cURL and slicing data using DOMDocument() function. Parsed page has "UTF-8" encoding.
Then i write data to database. But instead of

```
музыка
```

it is writing ASCII codes like this:

```
&#1052;&#1091;&#1079;&#1099;&#1082;&#1072;
```

I've tried iconv(), mb_convert_encoding(), utf8_encode, but still get the same. strlen() return the length of the coded string.

How to encode this to normal text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string ="&#1052;&#1091;&#1079;&#1099;&#1082;&#1072;";

echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

prints:

> Музыка